# jQuery: Using :eq and :not in a statement

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

**HTML**

```
<ul>
   <li>1</li>
   <li>2</li>
   <li>3    
     <ul id="sub">
      <li>3.1</li>
      <li>3.2</li>
   </ul>
 </li>
 <li>4</li>
<ul>
```

I am trying to select first few  <li> tags based on a condition and exclude any <li> that has a <ul> inside it with the id 'sub'.

I am able to get the first part but not able to exclude the li tags inside ul with id "sub".

Here is the jQuery code I am using.

```
$(columns[i] + ' li:eq(:not(#sub li)'+ j +')').css('padding-top', paddingTop);
```

Comment: 'j' is where the number of items in list to be selected is given. I select only few items in list based on a condition.

Comment: let's see the rest of the jquery code around this.  what is i? and please sell me you don't have more then one ul with the id of sub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the following HTML:

```
<ul id="main">
   <li>1</li>
   <li>2</li>
   <li>3    
     <ul id="sub">
       <li>3.1</li>
       <li>3.2</li>
     </ul>
   </li>
   <li>4</li>
<ul>
```

You can use jQuery like this:

```
$('#main > li:not(:has(#sub))');
```

...and here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yqrd5/

---

Or, if you only want to select among the first 3:

```
$('#main > li:lt(3):not(:has(#sub))');
```

...or dynamically:

```
var j = 3;
$('#main > li:lt(' + j + '):not(:has(#sub))');
```

...and here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yqrd5/1/

---

Or you might want the first 3 that don't have that `ul`:

```
$('#main > li:not(:has(#sub)):lt(3)');
```

...and here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yqrd5/2/

Answer (score 1):

Use the `:has` selector:

```
$('li:not(:has(ul#sub))').css('padding-top', paddingTop);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/62x3S/

That selects the `<li>` containing `<ul id="sub">`, which is exactly what you asked for. However, if you want to exclude the sublist as well:

```
$('ul:not(#sub) > li:not(:has(ul#sub))').css('padding-top', paddingTop);
```